# CakePHP returns ?? when querying MySQL for Chinese Characters

Tags: mysql, cakephp, encoding

We started adding Chinese language support to our application. Our DB Charset is set to UTF8 and I can successfully query from MySQL CLI and see the word in Chinese characters

However, when I try to use CakePHP query method "findAll", the value is returned as ?? instead of the Chinese characters

Our DB config in database.php looks like this:

```
public $default = array(
                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => true,
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'login' => 'root',
                'password' => '******',
                'database' => '******',
                'prefix' => '******',
                'encoding' => 'utf8'
        );
```

Also we have this line set in core.php:

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

We don't have any views set for this, we are using REST APIs so we are mainly just doing an "echo" in the Controller method for whatever response we get from the DB.

I also tried to create a test file and write this code in it:

```
<?php echo '基本' ?>
```

And it worked fine.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Never mind, turned out that I needed to install php-mbstring

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I needed to install php-mbstring which wasn't installed
Once I installed it and restarted apache, it worked like a charm